# Which whois servers are "thick" whois servers?

Tags: whois

I am looking for whois server that will provide domain names for all domains and not just those "local"

I found some

```
 {"whois.domainsrs.com", "whois.easyspace.com", "whois.indiatimes.com", }
```

Where can I get the rest?

I do not like the official whois server for .com domain, which is whois.internic.net or whois.verisign-grs.com. It doesn't seem to work the same way with others. Also my telnet sometimes jam when connecting there.

Comment: You are wrong. For .COM domain names you should first check the registry whois server (`whois.verisign-grs.com`) and then the relevant registrar whois server, at least until .COM finishes to transition over a thick model, planned for 2019. Same for any other TLDs: query the relevant registry whois server.

Answer (score 3):

The .COM TLD adopt a thin whois lookup model. You need to connect to verisign, perform a whois query, fetch the result, extract the endpoint and then perform the same query to the registrar endpoint.

The servers you listed are just 3 of the thousands accredited registrars. They are supposed to return a response only for the domains registered with them.

The only way to know which registrar is responsible for a .COM domain is passing by verisign.

Moreover, to answer the title of the question, generally every TLD is a thick whois server, except .NET, .COM and a few others gTLDs.

Comment: .JOBS is a thin one too, but all of them are expected to transition to thick in 2018/2019 as planned currently. There will not be any thin gTLDs after that.